# JLabel and the Frame

Tags: java

I have two questions. The first is that is JLabel shared? I know that JButton is not shared, however, imageicon is shared between the containers.

Question two is why can't I set the background color of the frame using the following method (Code 1 is the correct one, Code 2 is my version)

code 1

```
public class Q12_8a extends JFrame{
public Q12_8a(){
    Container c;
    c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("black");
    l1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("blue");
    l2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    JLabel l3 = new JLabel("cyan");
    l3.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
    JLabel l4 = new JLabel("green");
    l4.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    JLabel l5 = new JLabel("magenta");
    l5.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
    JLabel l6 = new JLabel("orange");
    l6.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
    LineBorder b = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK,2);
    l1.setBorder(b);
    l2.setBorder(b);
    l3.setBorder(b);
    l4.setBorder(b);
    l5.setBorder(b);
    l6.setBorder(b);
    add(l1);
    add(l2);
    add(l3);
    add(l4);
    add(l5);
    add(l6);
}
public static void main(String []args){
    Q12_8a frame = new Q12_8a();
    frame.setSize(200,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Code 2

```
public class Q12_8a extends JFrame{
public Q12_8a(){

    setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("black");
    l1.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("blue");
    l2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    JLabel l3 = new JLabel("cyan");
    l3.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
    JLabel l4 = new JLabel("green");
    l4.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    JLabel l5 = new JLabel("magenta");
    l5.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
    JLabel l6 = new JLabel("orange");
    l6.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
    LineBorder b = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK,2);
    l1.setBorder(b);
    l2.setBorder(b);
    l3.setBorder(b);
    l4.setBorder(b);
    l5.setBorder(b);
    l6.setBorder(b);
    add(l1);
    add(l2);
    add(l3);
    add(l4);
    add(l5);
    add(l6);
}
public static void main(String []args){
    Q12_8a frame = new Q12_8a();
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setSize(200,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your 2nd question / problem: I just tested both code blocks and get the same result. You should be able to do it with both methods.